# Windows 10 Taskbar App Drawer seems to have gone missing

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Normal windows 10 installations feature this small drawer in the right-most side of the taskbar, which holds all the background processes running on the computer (i think?).

[this is an example of such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHGZ3.png)

my windows installation does not have this, all the apps are spilled onto the main taskbar, and not neatly hidden away. i dislike this vehemently, but i have no way to know how to fix it. i have tried googling, but have yet to find anything regarding this problem.

[what my taskbar looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzjVY.png)

what can i do?

Comment: In Settings for Windows 10, look for task bar settings and then task bar location lower right.  See if it is set to bottom. Unlock the task bar before doing this.

Comment: Yes it is set to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Unlock it try moving the apps left .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. In the taskbar settings, go to Notification Area -> Select which icons appear on the taskbar.

[near the bottom of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVW7O.png)

[turn off Always show all icons in the notification area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM2wE.png)